# how to use isDisabled with custom arrow buttons in alice carousel react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel

I am using alice carousel in my react js project where I need to add custom arrows but my concern is I am not able to get disabled class in the arrows, can anyone help me with this?

```
 <AliceCarousel
  mouseTracking
  disableDotsControls
  responsive={{ 0: { items: 1 } }}
  renderPrevButton={() => {
    return (
      <a
        className={`slide-prev mr-2 cursor-pointer`}
      >
        <LeftArrowIcon className='text-2xl text-blue-dark opacity-[0.15]' />
      </a>
    );
  }}
  renderNextButton={() => {
    return (
      <a
        className={`slide-next mr-2 cursor-pointer`}
      >
        <RightArrowIcon className='text-2xl text-blue-dark opacity-[0.15]' />
      </a>
    );
  }}
  onSlideChanged={(e) => setActiveIndex(e.item)}
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer, we need to destructure isDisabled and then can apply condition as required.